# Correlated Subquery help in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, correlated-subquery

I need to find the last row for each ID in my table where a "Yes" was indicated and then search that same table for the next instance of that ID to ensure that the entry was a "No".  Presently This works just fine in a query combined with a php foreach that uses results from the first query in the where clause of the second.  The dataset is just over 3000 rows and the whole process is horribly inefficient at just over 4 mins to finish.

I know I can do this using sql only if I had just one Where criteria, but as I have two I seem to have hit a wall and appreciate any help I can get.

Thanks in advance.

```
//Get max dispatchID where Available = 'Yes'
    <?php $sql = "SELECT a.memberID, MAX(a.dispatchID) as lastDispatchIDYes
                FROM  members_availability a
                WHERE available = 'Yes'
                GROUP BY memberID";
    $qry = $this->db->query($sql);              
    foreach($qry->result() as $row){
        $sql2 = "SELECT dispatchID, memberID, 
                     FROM members_dispatch WHERE memberID = '".$row->memberID."' AND dispatchID > '".$row->lastDispatchIDYes."' AND available = 'No'ORDER BY dispatchID ASC LIMIT 1";   
        $qry2 = $this->db->query($sql2);
        if($qry2->num_rows() > 0){                  
            echo $row->memberID." switched availability at ".$row->dispatchID."<br />";
        }           
    } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats an idea to solve your problem.

```
select tableNo.*
from
    (SELECT a.memberID, MAX(a.dispatchID) as lastDispatchIDYes
    FROM  members_availability a
    WHERE available = 'Yes'
    GROUP BY memberID) tableYes
    (SELECT a.memberID, a.dispatchID as dispatchIDNo
    FROM  members_availability a
    WHERE available = 'No'
    ) tableNo 
where tableYes.lastDispatchIDYes < tableNo.lastDispatchIDNo AND
      tableYes.memberID = tableNo.memberID
```

This will fetch all the rows with available = NO, and whose dispatchID is greater then the last row whose available  was yes.

Comment: Thanks Zohaib, after 10 mins this query timed out, looked like what I had been trying though.

Comment: Have you considered adding indexes on columns to speed up the performance. In your case a composite index on memberId and available might help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you need, I think this query might help:

```
SELECT `a1`.`memberID`, `a1`.`lastDispatchIDYes`, `b`.`dispatchID`, `b`.`available`
FROM (SELECT `a`.`memberID`, MAX(`a`.`dispatchID`) AS `lastDispatchIDYes`
FROM `members_availability` `a` WHERE `a`.`available` = 'Yes'
GROUP BY `a`.`memberID`) `a1`
INNER JOIN `members_availability` `b` ON `b`.`memberID` = `a1`.`memberID` AND `b`.`dispatchID` = `a1`.`lastDispatchIDYes` + 1;
$qry = $this->db->query($sql);              
foreach($qry->result() as $row) {
    echo $row->memberID . " switched availability at " . $row->lastDispatchIDYes . "<br />";
}
```

Also, it seems that there might be an issue with the "echo" statement in the code sample mentioned in the question. The `$row->dispatchID` isn't a valid value in the resultset. I think it should be `$row->lastDispatchIDYes`. No?

**EDIT 1:** updated the query so that the "No" entry could by any entry for which dispatchID is greater than the dispatchID of the last entry with a "Yes". The original query above read only those "No" entries for which the dispatchID was immediately next.

```
SELECT DISTINCT `a1`.`memberID`, `a1`.`lastDispatchIDYes`
FROM (
    SELECT `a`.`memberID`, MAX(`a`.`dispatchID`) AS `lastDispatchIDYes`
    FROM `members_availability` `a`
    WHERE `a`.`available` = 'Yes'
    GROUP BY `a`.`memberID`
    ) `a1`
INNER JOIN `members_availability` `b`
    ON `b`.`memberID` = `a1`.`memberID`
    AND `b`.`available` = 'No'
WHERE `b`.`dispatchID` > `a1`.`lastDispatchIDYes`;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Abhay, This worked well and super fast but only returned 3 rows, there should be around 1200, perhaps the grouping or the join is incorrect, I'll keep working at this and thanks for the catch on the echo statement.

Comment: @SheldonPereira, good to know that it worked. There isn't any LIMIT to the query so I think there might be only 3 rows that match the desired criteria, i.e. maximum dispatchID with a "Yes" followed by "No" for the next dispatchID. But I can't really comment on this because I can't look at the data. Please feel free to let me know if you will need any help :-)

Comment: So the issue was the JOIN criteria, where you used b.dispatchID = a1.lastDispatchIDYes + 1 I actually needed b.dispatchID > a.lastDispatchIDYes....With that correction the query runs but is quite slow, I'm working on it, good base to start from, thanks.

Comment: @SheldonPereira, if the "No" entry need not necessarily be the next one to the last "Yes", there could be another way to write the query. Replacing "=" with ">" might slowdown the query as you had mentioned. I'll try to put the fix in my response.

Comment: Hey @SheldonPereira, were you able to test it? How did it go?